# Xamarin Forms: Hide a Stack While Scrolling a list

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin forms Page which is divided into 2 sections, the top 40% contains the Search controls inside a stack layout, the other 60% contains a list view. While scrolling the list view up I want to hide the Stack Layout at the top covering 40% of the screen.

I achieved to implement scroll events of the list from below reference:
https://github.com/velocitysystems/xf-controls/blob/master/XF.Controls/XF.Controls/Views/ListView.cs

I am able to hide the stackLayout but there is a lot of flickering. Any idea how can I stop the flickering? the output is not crisp and stable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use animation TranslateTo for StackLayout.

Example:

```
OnScrolled()
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        if (isScrollToUp)
            HeaderStackLayout.TranslateTo(0,-500);
        else
            HeaderStackLayout.TranslateTo(0,500);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put the search controls as the header of the ListView:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance/#Headers_and_Footers

As the header is a part of the ListView itself it will scroll as expected once you have enough content to scroll through.